# Selenium Python: Clicking on radio button that is not an input radio

Tags: python, css, selenium, radio-button

I seem to be having an issue with Selenium clicking on a radio button but from the looks of it, it's not an input radio button but an image to look like a radio button. Any idea how I would click on triggerControl2 which is the top button to turn on Use an external certificate.

[Radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeBoK.png)

[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt4WB.png)

```
<tr>
  <th>Certificate options</th>
  <td>
    <table class="middleAlign">
      <tbody><tr>
      <td><img id="triggerControl2" name="SSLCertModeImg" value="normal" onclick="this.guiAction();" src="../../../img/radio_off_normal.png" checked="false"></td>
      <td>Use an external certificate</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img id="triggerControl4" name="SSLCertModeImg" value="auto" onclick="this.guiAction();" src="../../../img/radio_on_normal.png" checked="true"></td>
      <td>Use a self-signed certificate (For test use)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show what locators have you tried so far that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, possibly need to debug this, but I guess the locator for the `triggerControl2`  button is `img[id="triggerControl2"]` `css_selector`.
Or if you prefer XPath `//img[@id="triggerControl2"]`

Comment: I have tried a wildcard for both css_selector and xpath, it's driving me up the wall.  


driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id*='triggerControl2']").click()


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'triggerControl2')]").click()

Comment: What this exactly means? I mean what error are you getting? Maybe your locators are not unique or you missing a delay / wait before that?

Comment: I just get the normal Unable to locate element on both on css_selectors and xpath, even with wildcards. Confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: Do you have a sleep / delay /wait before that code line? Maybe it is inside iframe?

Comment: yes has a 2 sec delay before the code, you know what could be in an iframe, didn't think of that

Comment: I'm just trying to guess what can it be. It would be much easier if you provided the link to that page..

Comment: Yep was in an iframe, *sigh*

Comment: So, now your problem is resolved and I finally can go to the bed? it's 00:30 here :)

Comment: Yes, you get a cookie

Comment: Great. So, if we could help you please accept or/and upvote....

Answer (score 1):

Try this css selector:

```
tr:nth-of-type(1) img[id*="triggerControl"][name='SSLCertModeImg']
```

Id seems to be auto-generated, that's why I added *.

To click use:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr:nth-of-type(1) img[id*="triggerControl"][name='SSLCertModeImg']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```

Radio-buttons sometimes are hard to click with Selenium.

Comment: This would be a nope

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[id*='triggerControl']").click()`

Comment: Updated the locator

Comment: still getting my usual Message: no such element: Unable to locate element, i even swapped the triggerControl to triggerControl12 and no go. 

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr:nth-of-type(1) img[id*='triggerControl'][name='SSLCertModeImg']").click()`

Comment: I got it, was buried in a iframe i didn't notice. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is why it is recommended to post the whole related html in your question.